# Canvas resizing with window - good way to do it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, user-interface, tkinter

i created a window with a canvas inside. The canvas contains an rectangle. Both change their size through a callback together with the window size.

So my beginner question is: It works fine, but is this a good or common way to do this? Or is there a more efficient/common way?

```
from tkinter import* #

#creating instance of tkinter
obj = Tk()  
#Set title of our window form  
obj.title("MyFirst Window - WOW")
#Set dimension of form 
x_size = 1200
y_size = 600
obj.geometry(str(x_size)+"x"+str(y_size)) 

obj.update()

w = Canvas(obj, width=x_size, height=y_size)
w.place(x=0,y=obj.winfo_height()-100)
w.create_rectangle(0, 0, obj.winfo_width(), 100, fill="#476042")

def callback(event):
    print(str(obj.winfo_width())+'x'+str(obj.winfo_height()))
    w.config(width=obj.winfo_width(),height=obj.winfo_height())
    w.place(x=0,y=obj.winfo_height()-100)
    w.create_rectangle(0, 0, obj.winfo_width(), 100, fill="#476042")

window = obj
window.bind("<Configure>", callback)

obj.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your question is in accordance with SO's rules and policies, but eventually might would belong to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry if this was the wrong place, i am pretty new to this whole ecosystem. I will take a look on codereview.stackexchange.com! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a good way to have the canvas resize. You should almost never use `place`. `grid` and `pack` make it much easier to create widgets that automatically resize.

For example, if you want the canvas to always be 100 pixels tall and fill the full width of the window, you can add it to `obj` like this:

```
w = Canvas(obj, width=x_size, height=100)
w.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
```

As for the green rectangle, you have no choice but to use a binding on `<Configure>` if you want the rectangle to grow and shrink along with the canvas.

However, your callback creates a new rectangle every time it's called instead of modifying the coordinates of the existing rectangle. This is a memory leak, because your program will use more and more memory the longer it runs and the more often the window is resized. `w.create_rectangle` will return an identifier; you can use that identifier to later modify the rectangle.

Here's a simplified version of your code. I've changed the variable names to make it a bit easier to comprehend.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()  
window.title("MyFirst Window - WOW")
x_size = 1200
y_size = 600
window.geometry(str(x_size)+"x"+str(y_size)) 

window.update_idletasks()

canvas = Canvas(window, width=x_size, height=100, background="bisque")
canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, window.winfo_width(), 100, fill="#476042")

def callback(event):
    canvas.coords(rect, 0, 0, canvas.winfo_width(), 100)

canvas.bind("<Configure>", callback)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Edit: Deleted my previous comments. Just one question left to grid. Is there a easy way to place a canvas directly at the bottom of a window? Also if I resize the window?

Comment: @K-Doe: sure, just don't put anything below the canvas. You also have to set the `weight` attribute for at least one of the rows above the canvas.

Comment: Oh well, that's in fact really easy. Works perfect! And again: Thank you very much!